# Identifying unique users in server-side tracking

Tags: unique, server-side, uniqueidentifier

I'm now learning about server-side tracking (as opposed to client-side), and I can't understand how the identifying of a unique user is done, when we use server-side method?
What I find on the internet, is only this phrase "unique id is generated and then mapped against a user every time they take actions". But I don't understand what originally allows to create this "unique id" in such a way that it is unique for every unique user.

Could you please share this in some broad terms - without a specific code, just the working principles and mechanics?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a cookie to store it while the user is anonymous. Then save it on the user when the user is created.

The tracking_id itself can just be a GUID. Pseudo-code:

```rb
def tracking_id
  @tracking_id ||= user.try(:tracking_id) || cookie_tracking_id || Guid.new
end
```

This will let you see a consistent activity stream across the signup divide.

I have some more thoughts in https://prefab.cloud/blog/opinionated-simple-identification-and-tracking-of-users/